# Embedded MySQL 8.0.17 fails with error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Command exited with error code: '-1073741515' and output: ''

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I am using embedded MySQL to run my JUnit tests, but since I upgraded from version 5.7 to 8.0.17, embedded MySQL fails to start with below error:

```
09/14-15:07:55.844|||main|||INFO||||||||The following 1 profile is active: "mysql"
09/14-15:07:56.654|||main|||INFO||||||||Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
09/14-15:07:56.826|||main|||INFO||||||||Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 162 ms. Found 57 JPA repository interfaces.
09/14-15:07:58.139|||main|||INFO||||||||Tomcat initialized with port(s): 0 (http)
09/14-15:07:58.155|||main|||INFO||||||||Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-auto-1"]
09/14-15:07:58.156|||main|||INFO||||||||Starting service [Tomcat]
09/14-15:07:58.156|||main|||INFO||||||||Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.4]
09/14-15:07:58.321|||main|||INFO||||||||Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
09/14-15:07:58.324|||main|||INFO||||||||Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2446 ms
09/14-15:07:58.552|||main|||INFO||||||||Embedded MySQL download path is /app/mysql
09/14-15:07:58.569|||main|||INFO||||||||Preparing EmbeddedMysql version 'Version 8.0.17'...
09/14-15:07:59.235|||main|||INFO||||||||Preparing mysqld for startup

    java.lang.RuntimeException: Command exited with error code: '-1073741515' and output: ''
        at com.wix.mysql.distribution.setup.ProcessRunner.resolveException(ProcessRunner.java:53)
        at com.wix.mysql.distribution.setup.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:38)
        at com.wix.mysql.distribution.setup.Mysql8Initializer.apply(Mysql8Initializer.java:33)
        at com.wix.mysql.distribution.Setup.apply(Setup.java:24)
        at com.wix.mysql.MysqldExecutable.start(MysqldExecutable.java:36)
        at com.wix.mysql.MysqldExecutable.start(MysqldExecutable.java:15)
        at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.Executable.start(Executable.java:108)
        at com.wix.mysql.EmbeddedMysql.<init>(EmbeddedMysql.java:47)
        at com.wix.mysql.EmbeddedMysql$Builder.start(EmbeddedMysql.java:169)
        at org.onap.so.db.adapters.EmbeddedMySqlDbConfig.embeddedMysql(EmbeddedMySqlDbConfig.java:92)
        at org.onap.so.db.adapters.EmbeddedMySqlDbConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$embeddedMysql$2(<generated>)
        at org.onap.so.db.adapters.EmbeddedMySqlDbConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
        at org.onap.so.db.adapters.EmbeddedMySqlDbConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.embeddedMysql(<generated>)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:645)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:548)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:59)
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:47)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1388)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:545)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:184)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:118)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:141)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:97)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:241)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:42)
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:72)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.LazyLauncher.execute(LazyLauncher.java:50)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.execute(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:122)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495)
09/14-15:07:59.559|||main|||WARN||||||||Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedMysql' defined in class path resource [org/onap/so/db/adapters/EmbeddedMySqlDbConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.wix.mysql.EmbeddedMysql]: Factory method 'embeddedMysql' threw exception with message: Command exited with error code: '-1073741515' and output: ''
09/14-15:07:59.564|||main|||INFO||||||||Stopping service [Tomcat]
09/14-15:07:59.600|||main|||INFO||||||||

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
09/14-15:07:59.626|||main|||ERROR||||||||Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedMysql' defined in class path resource [org/onap/so/db/adapters/EmbeddedMySqlDbConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.wix.mysql.EmbeddedMysql]: Factory method 'embeddedMysql' threw exception with message: Command exited with error code: '-1073741515' and output: ''
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:548)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:59)
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:47)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1388)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:545)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:184)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:118)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:141)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:97)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:241)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:42)
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:72)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.LazyLauncher.execute(LazyLauncher.java:50)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.execute(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:122)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedMysql' defined in class path resource [org/onap/so/db/adapters/EmbeddedMySqlDbConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.wix.mysql.EmbeddedMysql]: Factory method 'embeddedMysql' threw exception with message: Command exited with error code: '-1073741515' and output: ''
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:645)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
        ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.wix.mysql.EmbeddedMysql]: Factory method 'embeddedMysql' threw exception with message: Command exited with error code: '-1073741515' and output: ''
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
        ... 85 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Command exited with error code: '-1073741515' and output: ''
        at com.wix.mysql.distribution.setup.ProcessRunner.resolveException(ProcessRunner.java:53)
        at com.wix.mysql.distribution.setup.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:38)
        at com.wix.mysql.distribution.setup.Mysql8Initializer.apply(Mysql8Initializer.java:33)
        at com.wix.mysql.distribution.Setup.apply(Setup.java:24)
        at com.wix.mysql.MysqldExecutable.start(MysqldExecutable.java:36)
        at com.wix.mysql.MysqldExecutable.start(MysqldExecutable.java:15)
        at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.Executable.start(Executable.java:108)
        at com.wix.mysql.EmbeddedMysql.<init>(EmbeddedMysql.java:47)
        at com.wix.mysql.EmbeddedMysql$Builder.start(EmbeddedMysql.java:169)
        at org.onap.so.db.adapters.EmbeddedMySqlDbConfig.embeddedMysql(EmbeddedMySqlDbConfig.java:92)
        at org.onap.so.db.adapters.EmbeddedMySqlDbConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$embeddedMysql$2(<generated>)
        at org.onap.so.db.adapters.EmbeddedMySqlDbConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
        at org.onap.so.db.adapters.EmbeddedMySqlDbConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.embeddedMysql(<generated>)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139)
        ... 86 common frames omitted
```

I am using below embedded mysql dependency in my project:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.wix</groupId>
  <artifactId>wix-embedded-mysql</artifactId>
  <version>4.6.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You could always ask Wix. Looks like your error starts with their classes

Comment: The exit code usually indicates issues with required .dll files missing, not having access to, or having the wrong version. Apparently, mysql v8.017 has a missing .dll file issue under certain configurations. See https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94168 and https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=96573 for more details.

Comment: Is there any other mysql version I can try other than 8.0.17?

Comment: Any version above 8.0.17 :)

Comment: ok, but the thing is I am using wix-embedded-mysql dependency does not show version greater than 8.0.17 somehow.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.wix.mysql.distribution.Version.v8_0_34

Git url which I cloned:-
git clone https://github.com/wix/wix-embedded-mysql.git